# JSON Error while converting json into python directory

Tags: python, json

I am a new learner of Python programming. Recently ran into an error while running the following code. Appreciate any help in guiding me in the right direction.

````
        
        handle = open("json_input.json", "r")
        content = handle.read()
        
        d = json.loads(content)
        print(d)
    
    But keep getting the following error:
    
         File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 7, in <module>
            d = json.loads(content)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
            return _default_decoder.decode(s)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
            obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
            obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 7 column 5 (char 129)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error: `"JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"`simply means json_input.json is not a proper JSON.

JSON data should be use in double quotes.

You need to fix the json file first.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed there was an issue with the sample JSON text file. I corrected the sample JSON Text file and the issue is now resolved.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have any control over input json file. You can use [Abstract Syntax Tree(ast)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#module-ast) helper function called [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) like follows:

```py
import ast

handle = open("json_input.json", "r")
content = handle.read()
data = ast.literal_eval(content)
print(type(data), data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, as I am still learning to use to read JSON file using code json.loads, it doesn't lead me in the right direction. But thanks to you once again for your time in helping me.